# How to use DER encoded cert with mutual authentication in RESTful web service?

Tags: ios, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, mutual-authentication

Currently I am working on an app that uses mutual authentication in order to communicate with a REST interface. Because I am very new to this topic I studied several examples - and now I have some questions. I hope that I am able to stick all knowledge pieces together to gain a better view of the whole process.

The process should look like the following:

1. I got the exported server certificate which contains the server's public key and added it to the app bundle (which is later used for SSL Pinning).
2. The first Request, which represents the beginning of the 2 way authentication, is a Post Request which also contains a Certificate Signing Request to get a client certificate (which is required to talk with the secured part of the REST interface). The CSR is dynamically generated in code via openSSL lib.
3. The response of the server returns the signed certificate which is used for client authentication. This certificate is in DER Format and Base64 encoded.

The code I use to perform the SSL Pinning for the first request looks like the following and the SSL Pinning works as expected.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"server-cert" ofType:@"cer"];
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    SecCertificateRef certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0);

    NSData *remoteCertificateData =   CFBridgingRelease(SecCertificateCopyData(certificate));
    NSData *localCertificateData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];


    if ([remoteCertificateData isEqualToData:localCertificateData]) {

        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

        [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:[challenge protectionSpace]];

        NSLog(@"Certificate Pinning Succeeded");

    } else {

        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

        NSLog(@"Certificate Pinning Failed");

    }
}
```

But how do I deal with the returned certificate from the server? As far as I know I have to use the following NSURLConnection delegate methods - and to provide this certificate somehow to the server (for further requests).

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:   (NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    if([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {

        NSLog(@"Wants to Authenticate Server Trust");

        return YES;
    }

    if([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate]) {

        NSLog(@"Wants to Authenticate Client Certificate");

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

And

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

**Now my question.** I saw several examples using the PKCS12 Format (which requires a private key and the certificate authority) instead of a DER encoded certificate, to authenticate self against the server. But how do I use my signed certificate which is in DER Format in `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge for further requests? There is also an Android App which uses the same process for mutual auth, and it doesnt need a PKCS12 certificate.

Would be glad for some hints. Thx.

Comment: Related, see [Origin Bound Certificates (OBC)](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity12/sec12-final162.pdf) and [The Token Binding Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tokbind-protocol). Both rely on a long term, client side private key to keep MitM out of the equation. Unlike traditional mutual auth, the client certs and private key don't need to be issued by an organization.

Comment: Also see [Mutual-Authentication SSL with self-signed client certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16408312/608639), [Origin-Bound Certificates: A Fresh Approach to Strong Client
Authentication for the Web](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity12/sec12-final162.pdf) and [The Token Binding Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tokbind-protocol).